# how can i rewrite secured url in asp.net

Tags: url-routing, security

please look at below specified url

http://10.130.18.212/Test/(S(klcclla5uwjxijryxfvm3muj))/Quality/secureWelcome.aspx

i found this kind of secured url in various various web sites. please let me know how can i embed "(S(klcclla5uwjxijryxfvm3muj))" within the url. please let me know in detailed. 
to which concept it does belongs to in asp.net. kindly provide me reference url if any.

thanks & regards,
murali

Answer (score 0):

The (S(klcccla ... is being done by ASP.NET because you have cookieless sessions enabled.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx

If you want to use URL Rewriting with Cookieless Sessions enabled you should consider this solution:

http://www.urlrewriting.net/162/en/faq.html